# How to read all the Prolog predicate in a .txt file using read predicate in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am learning Prolog using SWI Prolog. Consider the situation in which I have a file named **myFile.txt** that contains the following content:

```
line1.
line2.
line3.
```

Now I am trying to create a predicate that using the **read** predicate have to read the content of this file, I have create the following predicate:

```
readFileSee(InputFile) :- seeing(OldStream),
                          see(InputFile),
                          read(Term),
                          write(Term),
                          seen,
                          see(OldStream).
```

The problem is that, when I execute this program, I obtain only the first line. For example if I launch this statement I obtain:

```
?- readFileSee('/home/andrea/Documenti/prolog/lezione6/project/myFile.txt').
line1
true.
```

The **read** predicate read **Prolog terms** but why read only the first terms? What can I do to let it read all the terms contained in the file? Can I do it using **read** predicate?

Comment: The manual claims that `read` reads the next term, not all terms in a file. I don't see you call read in a loop or anything, you just call it once. Why would you expect that it reads more than one term?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use repeat:

```
readFileSee(InputFile) :- seeing(OldStream),
                          see(InputFile),
                          repeat,
                          read(Term),
                          ( Term == end_of_file -> true ; 
                            write(Term), fail
                          ),
                          seen,
                          see(OldStream).
```

Comment: mmm I have understand your reasoning but seems that don't work because when I execute it passing my textual file the query respond me only true but write any terms in the Prolog Shell

Comment: looking to the trace seems as the Term is forced to be end_of_file but I am not sure about this

Comment: ok, I am pretty sure that the problem is that when you say:
Term == end_of_file -> true ; it unify Term with end_of_file athom, force to TRUE the result of the predicate and prevent backtracking...because if I delete this line when execute my line I say infinite end_of_file on the shell (as it read the string and after end_of file...), but how to avoid this situation?

Comment: (==)/2 doesn't unify, on purpose. repeat/0 must be stopped in some way, I've tested, seems to work...

Comment: do you use SWI Prolog? I know that A==B is the operator that check that A is equals to B but not unify...now I have solved in this way:
(Term == end_of_file) -> true ; (putting Term==end_of_file into ()

If I put int without () on my SWI Prolog unify !!! This is quite strange...do you use SWI Prolog or some other Prolog interpretation?

Comment: do you are under Windows or under Linux? This is so strange

Comment: what version of SWI Prolog are you using?

Comment: such code is surely stable from some year, no version problem, I think. Anyway, it's 6.3.12

Comment: mmm on my Linux I am now using the Version 5.10.4
I will try under Windows (here I have the last version)...so strange !!!